# SQL error in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Hi i am using rails and active record and there is some problem with my active record query.

```
session[:profile_ids] = [2,4,5]  
@profiles = UserProfile.where("key = ? and id in (?)", 'Noc_Address',
     session[:profile_ids])
```

But i receive this error:

```
Mysql::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'key = 'Noc_Address')' at line 1: SELECT `user_profiles`.* FROM 
`user_profiles`  WHERE (id in (361) and key = 'Noc_Address')
```

How i can correct it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`KEY` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) so you have to escape it:

```
@profiles = UserProfile.where("`key` = ? and id in (?)", 'Noc_Address', session[:profile_ids])
```

Or let Rails handle this for you:

```
@profiles = UserProfile.where(key: 'Noc_Address', id: session[:profile_ids])
```